# ERROR 1013 Restoring iPhone 4

Tags: itunes, iphone, ios

I have a MacBook 2.4 Intel Core 2 Duo version 10.6.6 i updated the iTunes to the newest version 10.2.1 & and an iPhone 4 .. when i was updating to the newest software of the iPhone a error occurred 1013, i went to the apple store and they change my phone.. i came back to restore the iPhone again (the new one) and the same error happened is it my iTunes or my computer making my phone break down?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Apple Support forums](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2655717&tstart=0), it looks like a fix for this is to comment out gs.apple.com in your hosts file.

Comment it out in /etc/hosts by doing the following (taken from that page):

- Open Finder
- Hold down COMMAND + SHIFT keys and press 'G'
- Enter "/private/etc/" in the field and press "Go"
- Find "hosts" file in the directory
- Drag the file to your desktop
- Open it in text editor
- Remove the line that has gs.apple.com entirely or put a # at the beginning of it to comment it out
- Save the file
- Drag it back to the /private/etc/ folder.
- You'd need to enter your username and password to authenticate the move